# Find unitary matrix whose first two columns are given.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a unitary matrix whose first two columns are $$ \biggl [1/2, \iota/2, 1/2, \iota/2 \biggr ]^T \text{and}  \biggl [\iota/2, 1/2, 1/2, -\iota/2 \biggr ]^T$$

I some how manage to find the other two columns by rearranging 1, $\iota$ and minus sign. What I obtain is

$$ \biggl [1/2, -\iota/2, \iota/2, 1/2 \biggr ]^T \text{and}  \biggl [\iota/2, -1/2, -\iota/2, 1/2 \biggr ]^T$$

I tried to solve using the fact A$A^H$= I But it gets hairy. I want to know the correct way of doing this problem.

Comment: [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram–Schmidt_process)

Comment: @t.b. I have tried Gram-Schmidt but failed. I don't know how to choose other two vectors to apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @Faisal: it doesn't matter which vectors you choose unless you are unlucky and they are part of the vectorspace spanned by the vectors given...

Answer (score 1):

Given vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ with $k<n$, you can add all the standard basis vectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$ to the list and apply the [Gram-Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) algorithm to $v_1,\dots,v_k,e_1,\dots,e_n$. If a vector  becomes zero after the subtraction step, you throw it away. Since the algorithm preserves the linear span of the collection of vectors, you are guaranteed to end up with a basic of the space.